# Check for equivalence of string and symbol

Tags: julia

I have a vector of symbols `a_sym` of length `N_sym` and a vector of strings `a_str` of length `N_str`

`a_sym` contains symbols at each index, such as `:H₅B₂O₆⁻`

`a_str` contains strings at each index, such as `H₅B₂O₆⁻`

I would like to check for equivalence of `a_sym` and `a_str` to see which index the equivalence occurs in each vector.

I have tried to implement a loop to check these two vectors:

```
E = zeros(Int64,N_sym)

for i in 1:N_str
    for ii in 1:N_sym
        if a_sym[ii] == a_str[i]
            E[ii] = i
        end
    end
end
```

Where `E` is my attempt to map equivalent indices, but my loop never detects the strings to be equivalent. How could this be remedied? (and perhaps simplified?)

For example:

`a_sym = [:H₃BO₃ ,:H₄BO₄⁻ ,:Li⁺ ,:H₅B₂O₆⁻, :H₄B₃O₇⁻]`

where N_sym would be 5, and:

`a_str = ["O⁻","H₃BO₃","H₄BO₄⁻","H₅B₂O₆⁻","H₄B₃O₇⁻","H₃B₃O₆"]`

where N_str would be 6. I require the loop to check both vectors and map the indices when there is equivalnce, for instance the index of H₃BO₃ in a_sym would be 1, and its index in a_str would be 2.

I expect a vector `E = [2, 3, 0, 4, 5]` which is filled with the indices of a_str, and 0 if a_str does not contain a match for a_sym

Comment: Wait a minute, my answer might be inapplicable... Are you really after some pairwise comparison, as indicated by the nested loops? Can you give some example input/output to clarify?

Comment: ```a_sym = [:H₃BO₃ ,:H₄BO₄⁻ ,:Li⁺ ,:H₅B₂O₆⁻, :H₄B₃O₇⁻]```
where N_sym would be 5, and:
```a_str = ["O⁻","H₃BO₃","H₄BO₄⁻","H₅B₂O₆⁻","H₄B₃O₇⁻","H₃B₃O₆"]```
where N_str would be 6.

I require the loop to check both vectors and map the indices when there is equivalnce, for instance the index of ```H₃BO₃``` in a_sym would be 1, and its index in a_str would be 2.

Comment: What would be the complete expected result for those example values?

Comment: I expect a vector ```E = [2, 3, 0, 4, 5]``` which is filled with the indices of a_str, and 0 if a_str does not contain a match for a_sym

Comment: Got it. I'll update my answer. In the meantime, edit in that information into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symbols and strings are never equivalent:

```
julia> :a == "a"
false
```

So you have to convert either to the other first.  I would write your function as follows using the builtin `findfirst`:

```
julia> E = [findfirst(==(String(b)), a_str) for b in a_sym]
5-element Array{Union{Nothing, Int64},1}:
 2
 3
  nothing
 4
 5
```

(Although, as Przemislaw notes, converting the strings to symbols would likely be more efficient.)

`nothing` is what `findfirst` returns if it does not find anything.  You can convert this to a default by broadcasting `something`:

```
julia> something.(E, 0)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3
 0
 4
 5
```

Comment: You should convert your `String`s to `Symbol`s rather than the way you did it. Comparing `Symbol`s for equality is much faster than `String`s. Additionally it is worth mentioning that when the lists are very long it might be worth to sort the list and indice pairs and than use `binarysearch` in order to optimize the performance.